# Node.js & SAML token : the right lib, approach?

Tags: node.js, saml

I'm given the following SAML token structure; It's injected by a firewall in a production environment. I've used JOTs so far and have no experience with SAML tokens.

My Express stack has a "token decode" middleware. I want it to do the "right" thing, like ensure the following:

1. Token validity
2. Signature validation (public signing cert is embedded in SAML itself)
3. Signing trust chain validation

Given the following structure, what's the best tool to validate a SAML? Moreover, does it need something more (ie. a "validation server", a key, etc... I don't know the SAML auth specifics...)

Thanks in advance,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ID="Assertion-uuida879c69c-0167-1543-bfc6-bd9d24e41ede" IssueInstant="2018-12-13T16:50:12Z" Version="2.0">
   <saml:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">TBD_A_COMPANY</saml:Issuer>
   <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="uuida879c69e-0167-131d-a363-bd9d24e41ede">
      <ds:SignedInfo>
         <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
         <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha512" />
         <ds:Reference URI="#Assertion-uuida879c69c-0167-1543-bfc6-bd9d24e41ede">
            <ds:Transforms>
               <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
               <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                  <xc14n:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:xc14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="saml xs xsi" />
               </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha512" />
            <ds:DigestValue>TBD_DIGEST_VALUE</ds:DigestValue>
         </ds:Reference>
      </ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:SignatureValue>TBD_SIGNATURE_VALUE</ds:SignatureValue>
      <ds:KeyInfo>
         <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>TBD_X509_CERT</ds:X509Certificate>
         </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
   </ds:Signature>
   <saml:Subject>
      <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">TBD_USER_ID</saml:NameID>
      <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
         <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2018-12-14T00:50:12Z" />
      </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
   </saml:Subject>
   <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2018-12-13T16:49:12Z" NotOnOrAfter="2018-12-14T00:50:12Z">
      <saml:AudienceRestriction>
         <saml:Audience>https://stage.eportal.TBD_A_COMPANY.com/B2EApp_IVCRED_SAML2_ISSUE_TrustChain</saml:Audience>
      </saml:AudienceRestriction>
   </saml:Conditions>
   <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2018-12-13T16:50:12Z">
      <saml:AuthnContext>
         <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
      </saml:AuthnContext>
   </saml:AuthnStatement>
   <saml:AttributeStatement>
      <saml:Attribute Name="mail" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">TBD_NAME@TBD_DOMAIN.com</saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>
      <saml:Attribute Name="sn" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">TBD_NAME</saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>
      <saml:Attribute Name="membership" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">CN=FSSO-Non Employee,OU=Azure AD,OU=TBD_A_COMPANY Groups,DC=corp,DC=TBD_A_COMPANY,DC=test</saml:AttributeValue>
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">CN=FSSO-Employee,OU=Azure AD,OU=TBD_A_COMPANY Groups,DC=corp,DC=TBD_A_COMPANY,DC=test</saml:AttributeValue>
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">CN=f5_administrator,OU=TBD_A_COMPANY Groups,DC=corp,DC=TBD_A_COMPANY,DC=test</saml:AttributeValue>
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">CN=splunk_f5_dtl,OU=Splunk,OU=Applications,OU=TBD_A_COMPANY Groups,DC=corp,DC=TBD_A_COMPANY,DC=test</saml:AttributeValue>
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">CN=isam_console_admin,OU=TBD_A_COMPANY Groups,DC=corp,DC=TBD_A_COMPANY,DC=test</saml:AttributeValue>
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">CN=Rally_User,OU=TBD_A_COMPANY Groups,DC=corp,DC=TBD_A_COMPANY,DC=test</saml:AttributeValue>
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">CN=Splunk_iowa_staff,OU=TBD_A_COMPANY Groups,DC=corp,DC=TBD_A_COMPANY,DC=test</saml:AttributeValue>
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">CN=vasps_wf_admin,OU=TBD_A_COMPANY Groups,DC=corp,DC=TBD_A_COMPANY,DC=test</saml:AttributeValue>
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">CN=RemoteLogonSTLVASOPS,OU=TBD_A_COMPANY Groups,DC=corp,DC=TBD_A_COMPANY,DC=test</saml:AttributeValue>
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">CN=vasps_Admin_Analytics,OU=TBD_A_COMPANY Groups,DC=corp,DC=TBD_A_COMPANY,DC=test</saml:AttributeValue>
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">CN=RemoteLogonIOWA,OU=TBD_A_COMPANY Groups,DC=corp,DC=TBD_A_COMPANY,DC=test</saml:AttributeValue>
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">CN=ws_operator,OU=TBD_A_COMPANY Groups,DC=corp,DC=TBD_A_COMPANY,DC=test</saml:AttributeValue>
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">CN=ws_administrator,OU=TBD_A_COMPANY Groups,DC=corp,DC=TBD_A_COMPANY,DC=test</saml:AttributeValue>
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">CN=InetDevl WebAdmin,OU=TBD_A_COMPANY Groups,DC=corp,DC=TBD_A_COMPANY,DC=test</saml:AttributeValue>
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">CN=RemoteLogonWebAdmin,OU=TBD_A_COMPANY Groups,DC=corp,DC=TBD_A_COMPANY,DC=test</saml:AttributeValue>
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">CN=GetLog-ITS-WA,OU=TBD_A_COMPANY Groups,DC=corp,DC=TBD_A_COMPANY,DC=test</saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>
      <saml:Attribute Name="sAMAccountName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">TBD_USER_ID</saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>
      <saml:Attribute Name="dn" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">CN=TBD_USER_ID,OU=TBD_A_COMPANY Users,DC=corp,DC=TBD_A_COMPANY,DC=test</saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>
      <saml:Attribute Name="givenName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">TBD_NAME</saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>
   </saml:AttributeStatement>
</saml:Assertion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[passport-saml](https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml) is popular. The library (if properly implemented...) will perform all required validation steps for you.